# Why are there two built-in int() functions?

Tags: python

Looking at the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), there is both an int(x=0)  and an int(x, base = 10). Why can't there just be a single function, something like int(x=0, base = 10)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a single function (or rather, a single type, which is a callable object).  The documentation is just written that way to show that there are two ways to use it.

Comment: I agree, although I wonder why in some cases the documentation shows an optional argument in brackets, and in some cases it shows it by re-printing the function signature.

Comment: @Brionius: for `int()` it's because the default is 0 if the base is not specified, but the value must be included if the base is specified. For others it may be because the uses are [completely different](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).